# Drupal show a custom message when deleting a field collection

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I have been using the **field_collection** and **field_collection_fieldset** modules of drupal-7. I have configured a **field collection** field (unlimited items) for a content type. So when i view the node, its content is displayed with all fields including the field collection items.

Now i want to change the message rendered on the page, when a field collection item is asked for confirmation to delete it, and when it is deleted successfully. (Specifically i want to change the **Label** of the Item being deleted).

Because currently the Label of the field collection item is displayed wrong (when i try to delete it and when it is deleted). Also the message displayed is different after the Label is deleted. So i want to change it.

For this, i found that i can directly go and modify 2 functions in the **field_collection.pages.inc** file. They are:

1. field_collection_item_delete_confirm
2. field_collection_item_delete_confirm_submit

Ex: Change the following line:

```
t('Are you sure you want to delete %label?', array('%label' => $field_collection_item->label()))
```

To this:

```
t('Are you sure you want to delete %label?', array('%label' => 'First Collection'))
```

And this:

```
drupal_set_message(t('%label has been deleted.', array('%label' => drupal_ucfirst($field_collection_item->label()))));
```

To this:

```
drupal_set_message(t('%label has been deleted.', array('%label' => 'First Collection')));
```

But i think that it is not a standard approach. So i would like to use a hook in my custom module to override those functions. I am not sure what hooks to use in my custom module. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Where is the code you want to override? Form function/page callback/other?

Comment: I hope it is a form function. Because the first function is triggered when i click on the Delete link beside a field collection in the node view, and the second function when it is deleted successfully.

Comment: Sounds like it will be then. `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` is what you're looking for

Comment: I can use hook_form_alter() to alter the content displayed on the page, when i click on Delete button. But is it possible to keep the existing content and just alter the Label of the item being deleted ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean - you can override the form submission functions in hook_form_alter if that's what you're referring to. But it may get complicated, might be easier to provide a new page callback through hook_menu_alter

Comment: Yes, i feel that hook_menu_alter() can better satisfy my needs. Can you give an example of how to alter the menu callbacks of the existing field_collection module, in my custom module?

Comment: i haven't got time to download field collection and check, but basically find the router path that drives the form (you can probably find it in  `field_collection_menu`), copy that form function to your own module and rename it, edit it, etc. Then implement `hook_menu_alter()` and replace the first of the `page arguments` for that path with the name of your new function

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved a solution to my problem, thanks to [Clive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830680/clive) for his valuable suggestions.

Here is what i did, to handle the deletion of a field collection item for a node:

1. Created a hook of type **hook_node_view()** in my custom module and overridden the delete link for the field collection items, so that they point to a custom path, that is declared in my custom module's **hook_menu()**.
2. Now the custom path is mapped to a template file (passing the field collection item id).
3. The logic inside the tpl file processes the deletion of field collection item (passed by id) using **entity_delete_multiple()** and sets a custom message to be displayed back to the node view page.

Done :)
This way, i don't need to modify the existing files of field_collection module, and still achieve the custom functionality i needed. Drupal is great!